# AngularJS: Longpress directive not working with function in controller's view on nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The onLongPress directive was working before I had to make an adjustment to my directives structures.

Now it's not working and I can't find why, perhaps someone can help me find my error.

The onLongPress should call a method from the controller assigned to the view, it doesn't, but if I add a `$scope.someFn = function();` inside the directive, it works, but I need to call a method from the view's controller.

How can I solve this?

The example is the next:

```
<my-tabs>
    <tab-one></tab-one>
    <tab-two></tab-two>
    ...
</my-tabs>
```

Inside each of this tabs I have lists.

Example inside  template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()" on-long-press="doOtherthing()">
    Some nice item.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Directives are as follow:

**tabOne**

```
app.directive('tabOne', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        transclude: false,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-one.html'
    };
});
```

**myTabs**

```
app.directive('myTabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/my-tabs.html',
        scope: {
            myMenues: '=',
            selectedTab: '=',
            general: '=',
            userPoints: '=',
            changetab: '&ngClick'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            // Some code to add functionality. Nothing fancy.
        }
    };
});
```

**onLongPress**

```
app.directive('onLongPress', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
            $elm.bind('touchstart', function(evt) {
                // Locally scoped variable that will keep track of the long press
                $scope.longPress = true;

                // We'll set a timeout for 600 ms for a long press
                $timeout(function() {
                    if ($scope.longPress) {
                        // If the touchend event hasn't fired,
                        // apply the function given in on the element's on-long-press attribute
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.$eval($attrs.onLongPress)
                        });
                    }
                }, 600);
            });

            $elm.bind('touchend', function(evt) {
                // Prevent the onLongPress event from firing
                $scope.longPress = false;
                // If there is an on-touch-end function attached to this element, apply it
                if ($attrs.onTouchEnd) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.$eval($attrs.onTouchEnd)
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UPDATE:**
If I add `$scope.doOtherthing = function() {};` into **myTabs** directive it works, but as I said, I need to get that function from the view's controller :/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try changing `scope: false,` to true in your tabOne directive and see if this fixes it?

Comment: Changed to true, it didn't work. Adding the Fn inside the onLongPress directive makes it work, but that's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: any chance you can put up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok, i will try, give me some time and i'll set it up.

Comment: Can't make the fiddle work, not even show the text. JSFiddle wins :/